# SQL query combine

Tags: php, sql, database

How can I get the same data of the below code using one query?
without using multiple requests.

I don't want to use multiple database requests.

```
$result = "SELECT classid FROM student_result_history WHERE s_id = 11 GROUP BY class_name";

foreach($result as $row){
  $classid = $row["classid"];
  $result2 = "SELECT term FROM student_result_history WHERE class_name = $classid GROUP BY term";

  foreach($result2 as $row2){
    $term = $row2["term"];
    $result3 = "SELECT subject_name, primary_mark, secondary_mark, practical_mark FROM student_result_history WHERE term = '$term' AND class_name = '$classid' AND s_id = 11";

    foreach($result3 as $row3){
        print_r($row3);
    }   
  } 
}
```

I want the result in nested array like

```
array(
    array( /*class_name 1*/
        array( /*term 1*/
            'subject_name' => 'abc',
            'secondary_mark' => 12,
            'practical_mark' => 30
        ),
        array( /*term 2*/
            'subject_name' => 'bcd',
            'secondary_mark' => 32,
            'practical_mark' => 20
        )
    ),
    array( /*class_name 2*/
        array( /*term 1*/
            'subject_name' => 'abc',
            'secondary_mark' => 42,
            'practical_mark' => 20
        ),
        array( /*term 2*/
            'subject_name' => 'bcd',
            'secondary_mark' => 32,
            'practical_mark' => 20
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You can use Union to combine multiple Select query into one that will produce only one resultset. You can learn the basics here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: You are not using any data from the first query. Why are you running it?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes he is?

Comment: Oh, he changed the question. Lemme look again.

Comment: @The_Impaler chek I'm using classid. 
I didn't use full code there (Query) I just use for show the loops and requests

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create a nested PHP array with SQL. Regardless of what your query does, it's just going to return rows, and you'll have to manipulate them in PHP to get the nested structure. Since everything you need is in the same table, there's not really a need to make the query that complex.

Just select all the columns you want with no grouping.

```
SELECT class_name, term, subject_name, primary_mark, secondary_mark, practical_mark 
FROM student_result_history WHERE s_id = 11
```

Then create the nested structure in PHP as you fetch the results.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $result[$row['class_name']][$row['term']] = [
        'subject_name' => $row['subject_name'],
        'secondary_mark' => $row['secondary_mark'],
        'practical_mark' => $row['practical_mark']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what database of version of it, so I'll assume it implements CTEs (most of them do). In this case a simple query should do:

```
with
c as (
  select classid 
     from student_result_history 
     where s_id = 11 
     group by class_name
),
t as (
  select term 
     from student_result_history t1
     where t1.class_name = c.classid 
     group by t1.term
)
select subject_name, primary_mark, secondary_mark, practical_mark 
  from student_result_history s
  where s.term = t.term 
    and s.class_name = c.classid 
    and s.s_id = 11
```

The nice thing of this query is that it requires minimal changes to the existing SQL queries you already have. It's mostly about combining the SQL parts you have.